# Can I drop into interactive mode at a breakpoint in pycharm3

Tags: python, django, pycharm

[image]

I am a fairly new Pycharm 3 user working on a django project.

Can I drop into interactive mode at a breakpoint in pycharm3? Is this possible? I have tried tools -> open debug command line when the program stops at a breakpoint, but I don't see a console opening. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can! Press the button I circled in green when you're at a breakpoint:)

[image: Pycharm console close-up highlighting cmd-line button]