# PyCharm console can't retun inserted variables in editor

Tags: python, visual-studio-2013, ide, pycharm, canopy

Suppose that we have this structure in `PyCharm`:

[image]

As we can see I inserted `rb` as bunch of random numbers in editor but when I insert `rb` in Python Console it will return an error. I don't have this problem in `Visual Studio python interactive window` and `Enthought Canopy`. What should I do to have same behavior in `PyCharm`?

Comment: You could always add the `-i` flag to make the program interactive after you run it. It is a short term fix.

Comment: Where should I add `-i`?

Comment: Oh, sorry, go to Run->Edit Configurations->Interpreter Options. I also will point you to [the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/run-debug-configuration-python.html) and [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207019/interacting-with-program-after-execution)