# How to interactively input the output of a code into another code and run them from Pycharm interactive python console?

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I'm using Pycharm community edition 2019.1 on Ubuntu linux, and I'm having the following issue with "memorizing" the variables from one interactive console to reuse them in another one:

Following [Interacting with program after execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207019/interacting-with-program-after-execution), and [Does Pycharm have Interactive Python Interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709105/does-pycharm-have-interactive-python-interpreter), I've done:

**pycharm > run > edit config > (ticked/checked) 'run w/ python console' (*formerly*, *'Show command line afterwards')***,

and it's "remembering" the values of the variables in the code and allowing me to interact with them directly in the console, but only the one corresponding to that specific program. For example, say I've two programs, 'test0.py'and 'test1.py'; from 'test0.py', we get x=1 as an output or variables used in it, and then we run 'test1.py' which takes x as an input. Now, since 'test0.py' and 'test1.py' have separate consoles, 'test1.py' isn't recognizing the x obtained as an output from 'test0.py'.

What I want is a global console like Spyder or Jupyter that'll 'remember' the output from and variables used in each of the programs that I run, and play with them.

What're the steps should I take to make the above happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try File>Settings>Build, Execution, Deployment>Console and check off the 'Use existing console for "Run with Python Console"' option. This will run the second program in the same console as the first one which should take care of your issue.